# PHP GET method undefined index

Tags: php, .htaccess

i have a problem with my form, this is script of my form

```
<form method='GET' action=''>
    <table>
        <tr>
         <td>Enter username </td>
         <td>:</td>
         <td><input type='text' name='user'></td>

        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

that form is redirect to SELF, and this my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/borrow$ admin/index.php?p=cpanel&m=manageBorrow [L]
```

but it showing undefined index for user variable,

anyone can help me solve it ?

thanks

Comment: Add php code and error

Comment: I think you need the Q,S,A flags to have the query strings appended. For example: `[QSA,L]`.

Comment: Is this u looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/php-notice-undefined-variable-and-notice-undefined-index

Comment: @AmalMurali: Your comment is indeed the solution for this problem and I believe you should convert your comment into an answer.

Comment: sorry , that work thanks to AmalMurali

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa):

> When the replacement URI contains a query string, the default behavior of `RewriteRule` is to discard the existing query string, and replace it with the newly generated one. Using the `[QSA]` flag causes the query strings to be combined.

So to have the query strings appended, add in the `QSA` flags, like so:

```
RewriteRule ^admin/borrow$ admin/index.php?p=cpanel&m=manageBorrow [QSA,L]
```